# I have imported an excel file in python and I am trying to make the 7th ROW the starting Columns. I need to hide the first 6 rowsHow can i do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I have imported an excel file in python and I am trying to make the 7th ROW the starting Columns. I need to hide the first 6 rows. How can i do that?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/sfreeman/Desktop/userexport.xls')
df
```

[image]

Comment: Did you perhaps check the parameters of [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/sfreeman/Desktop/userexport.xls', skiprows=6)
display(df)
```

Comment: It would be nice if this can be my first correct answer :-)

Comment: What's that last `df` doing there?

Comment: @Outserved If this answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: hi @Dominique, instead of `df`, you could also run `display(df)` to show the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/sfreeman/Desktop/userexport.xls', skiprows=range(7))
df.head()
```

Then:

```
df.transpose()
```

to make columns the rows, and vice versa.